# Working out the probability of the intersection of two events

Tags: probability

I can't get the probability of the intersection of two events to work out.

First, the sample space

$$
S = \{1, 2, 3\}
$$

Then we define two events

$$
A = \{1, 2\}
$$
$$
B = \{2, 3\}
$$

All of the outcomes are equally likely. So the probability of A is $\frac23$ and the probability of B is $\frac23$.

The events are independent, so the probability of the intersection of both events should be given by

$$P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$$

The result is $\frac49$. However, intuitively, this is not what I expect. The set from the intersection of both events is $\{2\}$ and so I expect the probability to be $\frac13$.

What am I missing?

Comment: They aren't independent. $P(A|B)=1/2\neq P(A)=2/3$. Why did you assume they were independent?

Comment: And the conditional probability $P(A\mid B)$ can be calculated by $$P(A\mid B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{1/3}{2/3} = \frac12.$$

Comment: I used $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$ to find the probability of the intersection of the two events, assuming they were independent. Now, I get that $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$ is actually the formal definition for independence and I should have used it to _test_ if the events were independent - not assuming they were. In addition, my understanding of independence wasn't clear. I found a better definition [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)), "Two events are independent if the occurrence of one doesn't affect the _probability_ of the other". Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The events, as you have demonstrated, are *not* independent.

Place three numbered marbles in a bag.  I pick one, look at the number and tell you whether or not is one of $\{2,3\}$ or not (just "yes/no").   Clearly your measure of the probability that I have picked one of $\{1,2\}$ will be affected by knowing this.

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(A) & = \mathsf P(x\in\{1,2\}) 
\\[1ex] & = 2/3
\\[2ex]
\mathsf P(A\mid B) & = \mathsf P(x\in\{1,2\}\mid x\in\{2,3\}) 
& = \frac{\mathsf P(x\in \{2\})}{\mathsf P(x\in\{2,3\})}
\\[1ex] & = 1/2
\\[2ex]
\mathsf P(A\mid B^\complement) & = \mathsf P(x\in\{1,2\}\mid x\notin\{2,3\}) 
& = \frac{\mathsf P(x\in \{1\})}{\mathsf P(x\in\{1\})}
\\[1ex] & = 1
\end{align}$$

Comment: This was very helpful, thanks!